# MongoDB model set of unique strings

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB where a document attribute "items" contains a set of unique Strings. It can either be modeled as an array of strings:

```
{
   _id : <Integer>
  items : [ <String>, <String>, ... ]
}
```

or as an dictionary with each string as the key and boolean set to true:

```
{
   _id : <Integer>
  items : { <String> : true, <String> : true, ... }
}
```

My two concerns are:
I want to add and remove Strings from items. And I want to do lookups, such as all documents where a certain String is in items. What would be the better solution?

I believe the dictionary would be faster, since lookups will be constant. Whereas with the array it has to run through the entire array in the worst case.

However, I am concerned about the Document Growth (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-operations/#data-model-document-growth). Especially, I am not sure what "adding new fields to a document" means in this context.

Would the dictionary grow faster than the array because of many different key fields?

Consider a collection with two documents:

as array:

```
{ _id : 1, items : [a, b] }
{ _id : 2, items : [c, d] }
```

or as dictionary:

```
{ _id : 1, items : { a : true, b : true } }
{ _id : 2, items : { c : true, d : true } }
```

Would the dictionary affect the document size more (apart of the additional booleans of course), since we have 4 new keys (a,b and c,d) in the collection?

Comment: Your dictionary example above defines "items" as a single sub-document. The problem with this is there is no way to index members of your items list so lookup would mean a table scan. Storing items as array elements would allow you to index items and to look for documents containing using $elemMatch in your query. As for document growth, will there be an upper bounds on items and do you expect them to change frequently?

Comment: So, the only downside would be a table scan for queries such as "find all documents where items has c"? Currently items do not have an upper bounds, but it might be wise to include one wherever possible. Items might change hourly but not that frequent.

Comment: Using the embedded document form would mean scanning every document and would be very inefficient. Your best bet would be to use an array. If you don't want to put an upper bounds on array size, a compromise you could make is potentially have multiple documents for an ID (not _id in this case), with up to X items per document. This is a pattern commonly used for time series data.